# array_diff() failing for no apparent reason

Tags: php, arrays

i'm trying to diff two arrays and php is returning the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Node could not be converted to string in D:\projetos\labs\dok\dev\application\models\dok.php on line 410
```

my arrays are, respectively:

```
array(2)
    object(Node)#5 ...[7 attributes]
    object(Node)#6 ...[7 attributes]

array(1)
    object(Node)#5 ....[7 attributes]
```

I would really appreciate some help here as I have no clue of what's going on. thanks (:

---

as requested, the code around the diff:

```
// is it a distant child?
$all_childs = $node->get_childs(true);
$distant_childs = array_diff($all_childs, $childs);
if(in_array($this, $distant_childs))
    return 'distant-child';
```

Comment: It would help to see the code around this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note:
>
> Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 ===
>   (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

If the element is object, you need to provide [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method for the object, or you did it by yourself.

Comment: wow! it worked just with a `simple serialize()`! I have to confess that i'm seeing this as a php "bug" :(